Error when calling SQL Server JDBC driver in Solaris
Has anyone had an experience with using SQL Server JDBC driver in Solaris?
I downloaded the driver from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16
I then created a simple Java class to make a connection to the SQL Server database:
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ExportToCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://Server1:4137;databaseName=db1;user=user1;password=secret";

        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

I compiled the class with no issue.
This is how I called the class from the Unix command prompt:
java -classpath /app/user/lib/mssql-jdbc-12.8.1.jre8.jar -cp . ExportToCSV

It returned this following error:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://Server1:4137;databaseName=db1;user=user1;password=secret
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at ExportToCSV.main(ExportToCSV.java:14)

What am I missing here?

Try explicitly loading the driver with Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); at the start of your main method. It might fix the problem, or it might provide an exception that gives us more information about the problem.

Also, you're specifying the classpath twice; which I think might cause the problem too (I think the last one "wins", which means the driver is not on the classpath). Specify it once, either using -classpath or -cp, not both, and separate entries with a colon (:), or - on Windows - a semicolon (;).
